# trigger in postgresql old value and new value

Tags: postgresql

how to write trigger in postgresql  which maintain old value, new value and table name.
I have 5 tables and each tables is different data structure i want to maintain audit details in single table with old value new value and table name.old value and new value  contain multiple columns in json format with column name and value.
example

```
audit_details
----------------------------------------------------------------
date_time|table_name|old_data|new_data|user|primary_key_of_table
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Just start with something and then fix the issues you encounter. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: See this blog post I wrote a while back [Postgres and JSON](http://aklaver.org/wordpress/2021/12/07/postgres-and-json/). It sketches out a similar idea.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote sample trigger function for you. You can make additional changes yourself.

```
CREATE TABLE test.log_table_data (
    id serial not null,
    schema_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    table_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    action_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    action_type varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    table_id int4 NOT NULL,
    old_data jsonb NULL,
    new_data jsonb NULL,
    CONSTRAINT log_table_data_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create or replace function test.register_as_log()
    returns trigger
    language plpgsql
    security definer
as $function$
declare
    v_old_data json;
    v_new_data json;
    shemaname varchar;
    tablename varchar;
begin
    
    shemaname = tg_table_schema;
    tablename = tg_table_name;
    
    /*  json_strip_nulls - removes null values  */

    if (tg_op = 'UPDATE') then
        v_old_data = (select json_strip_nulls(row_to_json(old.*)));
        v_new_data = (select json_strip_nulls(row_to_json(new.*)));
      
        insert into test.log_table_data (schema_name, table_name, action_type, table_id, old_data, new_data) 
        values (shemaname, tablename, 'update', old.id, v_old_data, v_new_data);
        return new;
    end if; 


    if (tg_op = 'DELETE') then
        v_old_data = (select json_strip_nulls(row_to_json(old.*)));
    
        insert into test.log_table_data (schema_name, table_name, action_type, table_id, old_data, new_data) 
        values (shemaname, tablename, 'delete', old.id, v_old_data, null);
        return old;
    end if; 
   
end;
$function$
;
```